# grow vs develop

Tags: comparison

I have always regarded "grow" as synonymous with "develop". After perusing the google search result of "grow vs develop", it seems that:

"Grow" applies to living creatures, whereas "develop" is used when it's about an inanimate subject.

However, In English, many terms can be used figuratively; so using "grow" on an inanimate subject seems acceptable.

For example, (from Magoosh GRE)

> "Tropical cyclones grow solely within warm weather systems."

However, the correct verb for this sentence is "develop" according to Magoosh.

Could someone explain why "grow" does not work in this situation if I use it figuratively?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Nothing wrong with using "grow" in this context. It makes perfect sense here. See [sense 7a](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00099456), in the Oxford English Dictionary online.

Comment: _Grow_ literally refers to simply getting bigger, while _develop_ implies other changes.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative definition of "develop" is:

> start to exist, experience, or possess.

So in this sentence, using "develop" is the correct option, since you mention that "tropical cyclones" start to exist in warm weather systems.

You should use "grow" for:

> (of a living thing) undergo natural development by increasing in size and changing physically.

But use "develop" for when something is starting to exist. Example sentence usage for this type of scenarios:

> A strange closeness developed.
>
> Large cracks began to develop in the wall.
>
> More rain will be needed to develop the plants properly.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote but I suspect it has to do with your view that develop applies when things start to exist. Babies develop into toddlers who develop into young children who develop into adolescents who develop into adults who develop into .....etc. And in your second example, you use **began** to indicate the start of something. May need rethinking.

Comment: Began to exist is a perfectly good meaning for develop.